# Rails installation fails in netbeans 6.9.1 IDE, in Ubuntu?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netbeans-6.9, netbeans-plugins

I,m getting the following error:-

ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    i18n requires RubyGems version >= 1.3.6

These the gems and ruby version installed in my system.
:~$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i686-linux]
:~$ gem -v
1.3.7
:~$ rails -v
Rails 3.0.1
:~$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe http://wiki.netbeans.org/RubyGemsNB6Ubuntu will be of assistance.